# How to add custom icon to tree and treenode

Tags: reactjs, antd

I m building a tree using antd tree ui component, and want to add my own icon example something.png or jpg file to each treeNode. How come I achieve this, please help?

Answer (score 1):

`Tree` accept a prop named `switcherIcon` and `TreeNode` accept a prop named `icon`. The props mentioned can be any valid `ReactNode` or `Function(props):ReactNode`. Usually it is best to use the default `Icon` component provided by antd but you can put your own `<img/>` too.

Example using antd `Icon`:

```
<Tree
  showIcon
  defaultExpandAll
  defaultSelectedKeys={['0-0-0']}
  switcherIcon={<Icon type="down" />}
>
  <TreeNode icon={<Icon type="smile-o" />} title="parent 1" key="0-0">
    <TreeNode icon={<Icon type="meh-o" />} title="leaf" key="0-0-0" />
    <TreeNode icon={<Icon type="meh-o" />} title="leaf" key="0-0-1" />
  </TreeNode>
</Tree>
```

Using your own custom image:

Define your component first:

```
const CustomIcon = () => (
  <img
    style={{ width: 15, padding: 1 }} // some custom style to look good
    src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/109/109688.svg" // use your imported .png or .jpg file instead
    alt="Custom Icon"
  />
);
```

Then use it the same way as previous example:

```
<Tree
  showIcon
  defaultExpandAll
  defaultSelectedKeys={['0-0-0']}
  switcherIcon={<CustomIcon />}
>
  <TreeNode icon={<CustomIcon />} title="parent 1" key="0-0">
    <TreeNode icon={<CustomIcon />} title="leaf" key="0-0-0" />
    <TreeNode icon={<CustomIcon />} title="leaf" key="0-0-1" />
  </TreeNode>
</Tree>
```

Here is a demo on sandbox:

[image: Edit zn9r60mpzp]